# Calculate area bounded by $\frac{x^{2}}{16}+\frac{y^{2}}{25}=1$, $y=\pm 3$ and $y=x+4$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> In my exam I was asked to find out the area bounded by the ellipse $x^{2}/16+y^{2}/25=1$, and the lines $y=\pm 3$ and $y=x+4$. Here is what I did.

$$\begin{aligned}A=\iint_{R}\mathrm dA&=\int_{0}^{3}\int_{y-4}^{0}\mathrm dx\mathrm dy+3\int_{0}^{3}\int_{0}^{\frac{4}{5}\sqrt{25-y^{2}}}\mathrm dx\mathrm dy \\ &=\int_{0}^{3}(4-y)\mathrm dy+\int_{0}^{3}\frac{12}{5}\sqrt{25-y^{2}}\mathrm dy \\ &=\frac{15}{2}+\frac{72}{5}+30\arcsin\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)\end{aligned}$$

Could someone check whether I have done it correctly. Any inputs are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You're correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is to verify the result geometrically by rescaling the equations with $x=4u$ and $y=5v$

$$u^2+v^2=1, \>\>\>v=\frac45(u+1), \>\>\>v=\pm\frac35$$

Then, $Area= 20 K$ with $K $ the area enclosed by the rescaled equations. Observe that $K$ can be partitioned as
$$K= K_z+3(K_t+K_s)$$
where $K_z$, $K_t$ and $K_s$ are respectively the areas of trapezoid, triangle and circle sector computed below
\begin{align}
&K_z=\frac12(b_1+b_2)h= \frac12(\frac14+1)\frac35=\frac38\\
&K_t=\frac12bh=\frac12\frac35\frac45=\frac6{25}\\
&K_s=\frac12r^2\theta= \frac12(1^2)\arcsin\frac35=\frac12 \arcsin\frac35
\end{align}
As a result
$$Area= 20\left(\frac38+3(\frac6{25}+\frac12 \arcsin\frac35)\right)=\frac{15}2+\frac{72}5+ 30\arcsin\frac35 $$

Comment: That was very insightful, thanks for answering.